# Distance matrix for mysql, based on previous solution for haversine distance calculation

Tags: mysql, matrix, distance, self-join

This question is self-answered to help people that need to create distance matrix in MySQL, which supports queries such as "select id2 from Distances where id1=10 and type1=0 and type2=1 and distance<10" which would find objects of type 1 in vicinity of 10 from object 10 of type 0.

*The code assumes table structure similar to one described in [Mysql Haversine distance calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula/7284463#7284463)*

If you ever find yourself in need of a distance matrix in mysql, here's a View definition for it:

```
select o1.object_id AS id1,o1.object_type AS type1,o2.object_id AS id2,o2.object_type AS type2,geodistance_km_by_obj(o1.object_id,o1.object_type,o2.object_id,o2.object_type) AS distance from (Coordinates o1 join Coordinates o2) where ((o1.object_id,o1.object_type) <> (o2.object_id,o2.object_type))
```

Where the `geodistance_km_by_obj` function is some distance calculation function, for example based on haversine calculation linked in the header.

```
CREATE FUNCTION geodistance_km_by_obj(object_id1 INT, object_type1 TINYINT, object_id2 INT, object_type2 TINYINT)
RETURNS float
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT 'returns distance in km'
BEGIN
declare sl1 float;
declare cc1 float;
declare cs1 float;
declare sl2 float;
declare cc2 float;
declare cs2 float;

select sin_lat,cos_cos,cos_sin into sl1, cc1, cs1 from Coordinates where object_id=object_id1 and object_type=object_type1;
select sin_lat,cos_cos,cos_sin into sl2, cc2, cs2 from Coordinates where object_id=object_id2 and object_type=object_type2;
return cast(round(acos(sl1*sl2 + cc1*cc2 + cs1*cs2)*6371,0) as decimal);
END
```

Comment: In order to stick with the Q&A format, you should pose this as a question, and then answer your own question with the solution that you came up with.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a delay of 8 hours between asking a question and answering it for low-rank users. Thanks for attention though.

Comment: It's been over 8 hours.  If you edit this question and select your own answer as the correct one you can earn an extra badge (there is nothing wrong with sharing knowledge on this site)